# How do I set the variables: AngularXDrive and AngularYZDrive of a configurable Joint in Unity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Joint myJoint;

Joint.angularYZDrive = 20;

does not work, although documentation says angularYZDrive is a variable of Joint class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`ConfigurableJoint.angularYZDrive`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/ConfigurableJoint-angularYZDrive.html)

-> it expects as value a [`JointDrive`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/JointDrive.html) ... not a float/int.

```
ConfigurableJoin myJoint;

...

myJoint.angularYZDrive = new JointDrive()
{
    maximumForce = AB,
    positionDamper = CD,
    positionSpring = DE
};
```

and fill in the desired values for `AB`, `CD` and `DE`